# Dash python-socketio notification emitting

Tags: python, plotly-dash, python-socketio

I want to send push notification using socket.io to browser from my py dash UI by clicking button event.

I have dash app running locally on port 5301 (http://localhost:5301/) with basic auth i.e. **user**='skuser' and **password** : 'pwd@skuser'.

Inside my dash program I have following code added in one callback

```
import socketio
.....
....
@app.callback(Output('send-notification-output', 'children'),
          [Input('send-button', 'submit_n_clicks')
          ])
def  send_notification(n_click):
   sio = socketio.Client(engineio_logger=True)
   print("sio client created")
   sio.connect('http://skuser:pwd@skuser@localhost:5301/')
   print("connected")
   sio.emit('notification_msg', 'hello world')
```

Now when send-button is clicked i.e. this callback is triggered in dash, I am getting following error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 333, in connect
engineio_path=socketio_path)

File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\engineio\client.py", line 186, in connect
url, headers or {}, engineio_path)

File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\engineio\client.py", line 296, in _connect_polling
r.status_code), arg)

engineio.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Unexpected status code 403 in server response', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\XXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 338, in connect
raise exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Unexpected status code 403 in server response*

**Please help me what is wrong in this implementation.**

Getting following info as well:

*Attempting polling connection to http://skuser:pwd@skuser@localhost:5301/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4*

Why **socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4** is added in the baseurl?

Please help!!

Comment: Socket.IO is a client-server protocol. You are creating a client inside your dash app, right? Where is your server?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Here Dash APP is  running on Flask Server port 5301.  I am leveraging the same to connect using socket.io client to emit the message.  Dash app  instantiated as below :          

 flaskserver = flask.Flask(__name__)

# instantiate the dash app

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    update_title='Loading...',
    server=flaskserver,
)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=5301)

Comment: I mean where is your Socket.IO server? I think you are not implementing this in the right way. In general when working with Socket.IO in a web application the web browser is the client, and the Flask/Dash/etc. app is the server. Having a client inside your server doesn't achieve anything if your goal is to communicate with the browser.

Comment: yes, after creating a socketio server, i was able to emit notification from dash app. So Socketio client is only communicated with socketio server. Now I have another question , once I  emit notification from dash  and receive emit back to my same dash app from socketio server, how I show it in red-circle notification in dash? any help will be appreciable.